# Finding the trajectory of a charged particle in space in a magnetic field

Tags: calculus, vectors, mathematical-physics

> I have been given that a charged particle of charge $q$, mass $m$ moving with a velocity $v_{0}(\vec{i}+\vec{j})$ enters a magnetic field $B_{0}\vec{i}$. At any time instant $t$, determine its displacement vector.

---

Let $a_{y}$ and $a_{z}$ denote the accelerations in the $y$ and $z$ directions. Then, $ma_{y}=qv_{z}B_{0}$ and $ma_{z}=qv_{y}B_{0}$. Using this, differential equations relating $v_{y}$, $v_{z}$ and time $t$ can be formed. Solving which does not fall into place with the answers provided.

$$\boxed{\left(v_{0}t, \frac{m}{qB_{0}}\sin\left(\frac{qB_{0}t}{m}\right),\frac{m}{qB_{0}}\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{qB_{0}t}{m}\right)\right)\right)} $$

---

I tried solving this involving the least bit of physics other than the standard formulas, and I cannot seem to arrive at the correct answer. Could someone check what is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to tell what is wrong if you don't write down your result.

Comment: Did you take into account that $v_x=\text{constant}=v_0$?

Comment: Answer is wrong. $y$ and $z$ should depend on $v_0$

Comment: @Andrei My answer is dimensionally incorrect. The boxed one is not the provided answer. It is the one I came up with.

Comment: It's evident you went wrong in imposing initial conditions.

Comment: You forgot to multiply with $v_0$ the last two components

Comment: Also, you did not specify at what point the particle enters the field. Is it $(0.0.0)$?

Comment: @Andrei That is because it was not specified explicitly. So I assumed the point of entry to be the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call $\omega=\frac{qB_0}m$. Then your equations of motion are:
$$\begin{align}\frac{dv_x}{dt}&=0\\\frac{dv_y}{dt}&=\omega v_z\\\frac{dv_z}{dt}&=-\omega v_y\end{align}$$
Note the sign on the last equation. The initial conditions for velocity can be written as $v_x(0)=v_0$, $v_y(0)=v_0$, and $v_z(0)=0$. The first equation gives $v_x(t)=v_0$, so $x(t)=v_0t$.

Take the derivative of the second equation, and use $\frac{d v_z}{dt}$ from the third to get $$\frac{d^2v_y}{dt^2}+\omega^2 v_y=0$$
The solution is $$v_y(t)=A\sin(\omega t)+B\cos(\omega t)$$
To find out $A$ and $B$ you need the initial conditions. First
$$v_y(0)=B=v_0$$ Then: $$\frac{d v_y}{dt}(t)=\omega A\cos(\omega t)-v_0\omega\sin(\omega t)$$ At $t=0$ you have $$\frac{dv_y}{dt}(0)=\omega A=\omega v_z(0)=0$$
So you get $$v_y(t)=v_0\cos(\omega t)$$ and $$v_z(t)=-v_0\sin(\omega t)$$
Now integrate with respect to time, to get the positions. Using the initial conditions will shift the center for $z$